# MySQL Trying To Avoid Union On DateTime Order

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My query is currently using a union between two select statements. I'm trying to avoid union. I want to grab the datetime of all times not greater than now ascending and have the expired times at the bottom of the query. Currently it's set like this:

```
(select * 
from 
  users 
where date > now() 
goup by users) 
union 
(select * 
 from users 
 where date < now() 
 group by users order by desc)
```

Comment: do you realize that what you're doing is simply selecting all rows where date != now(), and only sorting some of them? I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: im still new to this :/. ya i haven't fully tested my queries out. I actually took away the group by. I have to figure out how to organize the time before the group :/

Comment: does this query work in your database? group by users? can you do this and why do you need **group by** at all?

Comment: I suggest you give some sample data and your expected output. Would you expect a single user in both groups, for example? (the main part of your question would be answered with a `order by date` clause. You're missing the column name in your oder by.)

Comment: Sample data and expected results will be helpful.

Comment: PS: Nothing wrong with being new to this. ;) We were all new once!

Comment: @Ilion thanks ;)  im just trying to make a search function where it shows the user based on their last logged in time. I don't want to keep showing the same user over and over again :S

Comment: from that it sounds like `select * from users group by user having max(date) order by date` would work, but a sample of rows and your desired results would let me know if this is indeed the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to grab the datetime of all times not greater than now
>   ascending and have the expired times at the bottom of the query

This just sounds like you want a query of ascending dates.
The query would simply look, obviously, like:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY date
```

If you want to distinguish between your ascending dates list and your expired dates list, I suggest you just use two different queries, as such:

```
-- ascending list of date not greater than now()
SELECT * FROM users WHERE date <= now() ORDER BY date

-- list of expired dates
SELECT * FROM users WHERE date > now() ORDER BY date desc
```

Let me know if I'm understanding your question wrong.